# Mongodb Replicaset connection string unable to connect every time primary node in outside by using cluster IP

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, replicaset

**What did you do to encounter the bug?**
how to connect outside the cluster every time primary node. i deployed replicaset cluster and i get cluster IP by using this IP then i connect every time primary node in side node but outside its shows error so how to fix it.

[outside connection getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DapzF.png)

**replicaset connection string issue**
we deployed mongodb replicaset 3 node cluster and we create gateway and connected replicaset service using IP:Port connected but its not connect every time primary node so inside the node 1,2,3 we are mansion replicaSet=name then its able to connect every time primary but outside the node not able to connect primary and also we mansion replicaSet=name but it's show error so please guide me how to achieve outside the cluster i need to connect every time primary.
inside node connect every time primary as expected.

[inside pod we able to connect every time primary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4A8r.png)

**What did you expect?**
how to connect outside the cluster every time primary node.

**What happened instead?**
inside the node we able to connect every time primary but outside cluster not connect every time primary.

**Operator Information**

- Operator Version 1.18
- MongoDB Image used 5.0.15

**What did you expect?**
how to connect outside the cluster every time primary node.

[outside connection getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DapzF.png)

[connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95TEi.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: See the examples in [Connection String URI Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) for Replica Sets. Any you man add option `readPreference=primaryPreferred`